# laravel file upload - The "" file does not exist or is not readable

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

When I am uploading a file above 5mb I get the following error,

> The "" file does not exist or is not readable.

This only happens once file sizes creep up towards 5mb, I cannot understand why this would be a problem, below is my code,

```
public function verifySave(Request $request)
{
    $path = Storage::disk('local')->put('verification', $request->file('certificate'));
    //$path = $request->file('certificate')->putFileAs('verification');
    $newPath = \Storage::disk('local')->path($path);
    if(strpos($request->file('certificate')->getMimeType(), "image") !== false) {
        $pdf = new Fpdf();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image($newPath, 0, 0, -300);
        $newPath = \Storage::disk('local')->path('verification/' . $request->file('certificate')->hashName() . '.pdf');
        $pdf->Output('F', $newPath);
    }

    $verification = [
        'death_certificate' => $newPath,
        'uploaded' => 'Yes',
        'method' => $request->input('verify_method')
    ];
    $request->session()->put('verification', $verification);
    return redirect('/your-details');
}
```

Comment: try `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M')` and `ini_set('post_max_size', '500M')`

Answer (score 5):

If someone else gets this error and it doesn't turn out to be a permissions issue, check your `php.ini` file.

Make sure that your `upload_max_filesize` is as big as your `post_max_size`. I had 1000M for `post_max_size` (we deal with some big ol' video files), but only 100M for `upload_max_size` (I blame my old eyes). The upload would churn for a long time, and then throw the error above.

Comment: saved me hours here.... thank you